# Javascript not retaining div id on reload with localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to have three links, which will show a div when you click on them. If you click on these links again, another type of that link will be shown. For example, if I have the link `one`, clicking on it will produce div `one`. Clicking on it again will produce div `one1`. This way, each element has a unique id, and can have custom styles applied to individual divs at a later time.

When the user clicks one of the `a` links, it creates a localStorage key for how many times that type of div was clicked. For example, if I click div `one`'s line `5` times, the localStorage key would be 5. Then when the page is reloaded, my script duplicates the div onto the page 5 times, and sets the counter for part 1 to 5. This way, when you start clicking on the `a` links again, they don't start from 1, but from 5, so that they're aren't any conflicting ID's.

The problem I am running into is the delete function. Say the user duplicated `5` of div `one`. That means that `one1, one2, one3, one4, one5` are all present on the screen. If the user reloads the page, they're all still there. Let's say the user deletes `div1` from the page though. It removes `div1` and all styling associated with it, and leaves the other divs in tact...

**BUT**, if you reload the page, the script duplicates the div's starting from `1-4` (as they're were only 4 divs saved to the localStorage key), instead of duplicating from `2-5`, as `#1`, or `div1`, was deleted.

I realize that's a lot to read, and might be tough to understand, so I made a fiddle with the code in it.

http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/bMzME/2/

To test what I'm saying, you have to show a number of div's, say 5 of "one". You'll notice that `#one1, #two1, and #three1` all have a border to them, to show what happens when you delete them. As you duplicate the divs, `div1` will have the border. If you delete that div, the other div's on the page won't be affected until you reload the page. Once you reload, you'll notice that the former `div2` has had it's id changed to `div1`, instead of keeping it at `div2`.

Is there anyway to fix this without having to rewrite the entire script? I feel like there might be a quicker way to fix it, and I just can't picture it.

<sub>PS, if you read all of that above, I am honestly thankful</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just couldn't get your code to work, sorry.

I did however manage to achieve roughly what you describe: http://jsfiddle.net/bMzME/11/

Comment: The code in my example is working, though. What were the errors you got? And thanks for the fiddle, why do you say "roughly"?

Comment: What I meant  was, I couldn't fix your code (I'm lazy). It was working the way you said it did.

Comment: Ah, no problems. The only thing I changed with your code was the use of the `data` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I believe one of the issues is that you are just keeping count of the #one, #two, #three and using that to create the div IDs dynamically.

What you need is a data structure that holds all `i` such that `div{i}` is present. Probably create a list and map it to your key which is #one, #two, #three. Then you get the list and iterate over the elements in `$(".base")` for-loop.

Now if you had 5 div ones and you deleted the 5th one, you will have one1, one2, one3, one4. If now I insert another div **one** do you want that at 5 or 6? If you want at "5" simply take the `max()` from your list else use a separate counter as shown below - see var: idx. Then add idx to your list - I haven't coded the list. I will try my solution but will take some time - not all to familiar with JS. But the idea should work I believe.

```js
$(".a").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    var id = $(target).attr("id");
    var x = $("." + id).size();
    var click = $(target).data("clicked") || x;
    var idx = localStorage.getItem(target+"i");
    $(target).data("clicked", ++click);
    if (idx == null) {idx = 1;}
    var name = id + idx;
    alert(name);
    $(target).clone().attr("id", name).attr("class", "drag " + id).appendTo("body");
    localStorage.setItem(target, click);
    localStorage.setItem(target+"i", ++idx);
});
```

Comment: Btw, your code worked for me with the exact issues you described in your question.

Comment: Ignore comment above! Please check out http://jsfiddle.net/WiseOwl/nV6bx/; I have some alerts. I have implemented the list I was mentioning as a string of indexes. Also, added a class to you main HREFs otherwise your ${a} is called on CLOSE hrefs too which I believe you do not want? The only part of your code not working was that the hyperlinks of newly added elements do not work until you refresh the page. I believe you should define your ${".close"} functionality in a named function and assign it the elements you add using .appendToBody.